# Is Street Fighter IV mulitplayer cross-platform?

Tags: street-fighter-iv

I'm considering picking up Street Fighter IV on PC, and I'm wondering: Does the networked multiplayer allow PC users and PS3/Xbox users play together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Street Fighter IV does not offer cross-platform multiplayer.

However, Capcom has, for certain events, hosted cross-platform multiplayer matches for a limited number of selected players. (PS3 vs. Xbox360)

Comment: So it's technically possible, but they just decided gamers wouldn't want it/they thought it would give them a competitive edge? Typical

Comment: There is a 2 frame time delay between PS3 an XBOX360 http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_124938&feature=iv&src_vid=uyrwGA5GND0&v=tx1StGj0pII and it would be unfair to XBOX360 players, as they have to pay for the GOLD membership, whereas PC and PS3 do not require you to pay an additional fee for online play.